# Is it safe to install Ubuntu from a bootable USB made on pirated Windows 7?

Tags: system-installation, windows, security

I found out that I was using a pirated version of Windows 7, so I migrated to Linux OS by downloading an .ISO file and making a USB bootable via Rufus.

People says that using pirated versions is risky because they may have malware and viruses that can automatically be saved in files and folders so I'm not sure that is it safe and legal to install Linux from a pirated version of Windows does infected files still remains in Linux version or not.

Is there anything I need to do in this situation?

Comment: If you verify the ISO is valid (do the verification on another box as well to be sure), validate the write of the ISO to media (you didn't mention any release so this step maybe automatically done for you and you can see results; or may require additional step) you should okay if you didn't skip any steps. Did you grab Lubuntu from a *legitimate* web site? and install per directions?  https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html  (manual for *latest stable* release as you didn't provide release details; adjust *stable* if using *lts* for example)

Comment: There is nothing *illegal* with downloading an Ubuntu (or *flavor* of Lubuntu like Lubuntu) ISO, writing to media & installing it; though this is *layman* advice as we don't know your location/country & thus what laws apply to you; but licenses are available for all Ubuntu software if you look so you can actually check for yourself & your local region.

Comment: Yes thanks for your reply

I installed Ubuntu 21.04 from an official website below

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

The thing is installing Linux into pendrive from pirated version and injecting same pendrive in linux is it safer 

Also I need to copy my files I made in windows pirated version in Linux now is it safer or viruses made only for OS like windows so below someone commented it is made for specific OS...

Comment: If it was me, I'd verify the thumb-drive on a second box (I'd use a *testbox* or VM) to ensure a validation of media completes successfully..  as if it's a *faulty* ISO (impacted by malware) the self-validation of the media can give misleading results (why you still need to check ISO checksum before writing to media).  I'd use a *live* system to copy your files off; possibly use `clamav` or like to scan for malware before and likely after the copy to check for issues... Windows malware only really impacts windows; but an infected `chrome` config will impact any OS `chrome` so use common sense

Comment: yes I got your answer and appreciate your efforts

if I installed an antivirus named "ClamAV" and scan every files before opening or working so is it safer because I have about 3 Years of work from windows pirated version now I wanna use in Linux based OS with safe side.:)

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2449090

Answer (score 5):

If you verify the ISO is valid (*do the verification on another box as well to be sure*), validate the write of the ISO to media (*you didn't mention any release so this step maybe automatically done for you and you can see results; or may require additional step*) you should okay if you didn't skip any steps.

Did you

- grab Lubuntu from a *legitimate* web site?
- and install per directions?

https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html

manual for *latest stable* release as you didn't provide release details; adjust *stable* if using *lts* for example

There is nothing *illegal* with downloading an Ubuntu (or *flavor* of Lubuntu like Lubuntu) ISO, writing to media & installing it; though this is *layman* advice as we don't know your location/country & thus what laws apply to you; but licenses are available for all Ubuntu software if you look so you can actually check for yourself & your local region.

Note:   If unsure which web site to download form, do **not** ask google unless you can peruse the results offered & pick the correct one (google offers a number of sites to download & many are *fan* or *fake*).  If you want a Ubuntu *flavor* like Ubuntu you should go to [Ubuntu.com and then go to the official *flavor* site](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) for your download.

Comment: This mentions Lubuntu (and uses Lubuntu link for manual etc) as it's what was originally *tagged* by OP, later comment now says Ubuntu; I haven't corrected as *Lubuntu* is still tagged in question.

Comment: yes I got your answer and appreciate your efforts if I installed an antivirus named "ClamAV" and scan every files before opening or working so is it safer because I have about 3 Years of work from windows pirated version now I wanna use in Linux based OS with safe side.:)

Comment: I'd boot a *live* system (eg. Ubuntu media on thumb-drive) and scan before you copied your files (ie. install `clamav`, update it's signatures etc & run from the *live* system; I've done this many times to scan various windows machines (not mine) where users have issues) to work out how safe it is, then on completion I'd likely reboot & copy the files then... reboot & scan the copy (I'd even consider using different OS/release for this scan) but what you do is up to you; I have no experience with *unlicensed windows* only licensed that users have infected via careless downloads.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and precious time...

Answer (score 1):

how are you doing?

From what I understand it is very unlikely that you would get a virus from a bootable usb drive on your Linux installation.
You see, if the malware was coded for Windows, it is unlikely to work on Linux, because viruses are coded to act on a specific system.
As for being illegal, I don't think you're going to get in trouble for using a pirated version of windows, especially if it came with the computer, but it's a good thing you switched for a linux distribution from Windows 7 due to the lack of support from Microsoft and also because Linux is more efficient and secure.
I hope I helped you in some way.

Comment: yes I got your answer and appreciate your efforts if I installed an antivirus named "ClamAV" and scan every files before opening or working so is it safer because I have about 3 Years of work from windows pirated version now I wanna use in Linux based OS with safe side.:)

Comment: nice, but I wouldn't worry about using anti virus on linux, it's pretty safe, I'm using it for around ten years and never had any problems with viruses, but it's always good to check right, have a great week!